# Websphere Clustering on a single standalone

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing

I want to create a cluster of Websphere Application Server nodes on a standalone machine. Is it possible to create it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can only cluster a WebSphere *Network Deployment*, not a standalone installation. There is nothing preventing you from only having one cluster member though, but you still need to set it up as it's own cell, with a deployment manager and a network deployment.